# Download file served by a page using wget

Tags: linux, http, wget

I am trying to download a file served by [a particular page](http://www.dli.gov.in/scripts/FullindexDefault.htm?path1=/data7/upload/0180/365&first=35&last=479&barcode=2030020017599) in linux using wget. Note that I don't want to download the html page itself, but the .tiff file that is downloaded when the page loads. If I use

```
wget http://www.dli.gov.in/scripts/FullindexDefault.htm?path1=/data7/upload/0180/365&first=35&last=479&barcode=2030020017599
```

then it downloads the webpage instead of the tiff file served by it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use chrome you can view the `.tiff` file's url .If you get it, you just command this:

```
wegt the-url-of-.tiff
```

Bingo!

Comment: How do I get the URL of the tiff file in chrome?

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + J`or `Cmd + Opt + J.` Then click network tab

Answer (score 0):

You can try an alternative i.e cURL command. Its usage is: curl -O url.
Make sure about permissions and other stuff like that.